# Expected number of children until # of boys equals # of girls?

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability

A couple decide to start having children and keep having children until they have the same number of boys and girls. How many children do they expect to have?

Using intuition, I get an answer of 2, but I'm not sure how to prove it mathematically or if it fits any sort of probability distribution model.

Comment: The [expected return time of a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2109655/9340) is $\infty$.

Comment: To explain the relevance of Sangchul's post: consider the "number" of children the couple has, and call it $C$. It starts at zero; add one to $C$ if they get a girl, and subtract one from $C$ if they get a boy. This is like walking randomly left to right along the integers with probability $1/2$ for each direction, and the number of children they have in total is the number of steps taken on your first return to $0$ (the return time).

Comment: As for the result of $2$, it should actually be intuitive that this _cannot_ be the answer: What is the smallest number of children we can have such that the number of boys equals the number of girls?