# Random walk 1D with a single bound

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider a one dimensional random walk, where we have a bound at 0 and no upper bound. Also consider that we start at point: 1. My question is how many steps will it on average take to reach zero. If we reach zero the random walk stops. The probability of moving to the left as to the right is equal. Thus $p = q = 1/2$.

I tried solving this using a Monte Carlo simulation, however I'm not even sure if you are guaranteed to always reach the bound.

The problem could also be made more general, for example starting at any point n, or making the probability of moving to the left $p$ and to the right $1-p$.

Comment: What happened in your simulation? I.E what statistics did you get on number of steps? Did some trials result in never getting back to zero?

Comment: Yes, that is why I'm not sure if you will ever reach the bound. It could also likely be some programming error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, the average number of steps does not exist.

To show this, suppose that the average (read: expected value) of the number of steps to move 1 step backward exists and is equal to $x$. We can make an equation for $x$ by multiplying the probability of each direction by the expected number of steps based on each direction. If we get a backwards step, then it only takes $1$ step. If we get a forward step, then we have $1$ step, plus the average number of steps to get back to the original position, plus the average number of steps to go backward. This becomes the equation:

$$x=\frac{1}{2}(1)+\frac{1}{2}(1+x+x)$$
$$\Rightarrow x=1+x$$

But this is a contradiction, so there is no finite average number of steps.

Comment: But how can you say that, if one goes one step away from 0, then the only way to get back to before that is to do it right away? You might go 1+1+1 away from 0  and then 1+1+1+1 back toward 0, for example.

Comment: @coffeemath I'm not sure I understand your question, but it might help to remember that $x$ is the average/expected number of steps to reach a point 1 space backward, not (as you seem to be discussing) the number of steps for any given random walk.

Comment: I found this on this site that seems to me to cover the OP question, and it seems more complicated than your approach. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087996/bounded-random-walk-on-one-side-only-are-you-guaranteed-to-hit-the-bound

Comment: Angelica--- I read the linked answer of my last comment more carefully, and it is about the probability of returning to 0 at least once, given you start at 1. That is different than the *expected value* of the number of steps to get back to zero. So I'm inclined to agree with your answer [already upvoted before...]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think it solves the problem in a very clear way. As for the link @coffeemath sent, it is a bit counter intuitive that the probability you reach the bound is 1 but the expected number of steps it would take is not finite. Or is this not correct?

Comment: @JsnDvL As you say the probability (for 1/2 prob back or forward) to reach bound is 1. And the expected number of steps to do that is not finite. Maybe another proof of not finite can be done based on computing enough distinct ways to get there in $n$ steps (and their probabilities), and showing the sum of (ways to get there in n steps)*(probabilityof each way) goes to infinity.